# Best Analytics tool for Django Rest Framework API management?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, charts, maps, analytics

I know this is not right place to ask this kind of question but haven’t had any option

We use Django Rest Framework for backend APIs, we have almost 40 Apis which gets use back and forth what is the best place to measure analytics for them,

Note:

1. We use primarily "maps” which is a combination of Mapbox and Map-tiler.
2. We want to visualise the API calls on maps.
3. We want to compare them on graphs

Earlier we used graphana with Prometheus to measure the api calls but now after a month  we realised that is majorly meant for server analytics.

Now there are almost 100s of cloud services available on google which provide these kind of analytics but which one is the best for our case I really don’t know and the worst part and every one of them looks so similar to one another so how they are different could only be learnt after trying them all.

Answer (score 0):

So I have chosen to go with [APIgee](https://cloud.google.com/apigee) it seems quite promising they are giving a 60 days evaluation time period also, But their pricing is not clear. Let's hope for the best